# Error al emparejar dispositivo bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-permissions

hace tiempo vengo desarrollando una aplicación y me funcionaba normal la impresión por Bluetooth hasta que se actualizó el software del celular, se empezó a hacer más lenta la conexión después de la actualización 6.0 Marshmallow del teléfono, luego no conectaba a la primera si no que tocaba darle varias veces hasta que lo lograba y ahora no conecta; me sale el siguiente error:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH PRIVILEGED permission:
>   Neither user 10218 nor current process has
>   android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED.

En el Manifest están bien declarados los permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED"/>
...
...
...
```

He buscado mucho y realmente no se que hacer. Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan dar, me estoy volviendo loco...
El Bluetooth enciende, encuentra el dispositivo necesario pero a la hora de emparejar

```
mmDevice.setPairingConfirmation(true);
```

me sale el error. Como dije antes, funcionaba muy bien hasta que se actualizó el software del celular ahora es Android 7.0 Nougat.

Comment: Que exactamente es que que intentas hacer? Enviar archivos o emparejar dispositivos para que se conozcan unos a otros?

Comment: Hola Einer, lo que intento hacer es emparejar con una impresora y mandar a imprimir algo, solo eso, luego se desconecta, pero no quiero que el usuario tenga que darle permiso cada que vaya a imprimir.

Answer (score 1):

En este caso ambas aplicaciones deben tener el permiso [BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED)

> [BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED) Permite a las aplicaciones emparejar
>   dispositivos bluetooth sin la interacción del usuario, y permite o no
>   el acceso a la libreta de direcciones o el acceso a los mensajes. **NO  disponible para aplicaciones de terceros.**

**Pero para poder asignar este permiso tu aplicación debe ser configurada como aplicación de sistema**, si tu aplicación no es de sistema, aunque tengas configurados los permisos, estos no podrán ser asignados:

> Java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH PRIVILEGED permission:
>   Neither user 10218 nor current process has
>   android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED.

Te sugiero estos artículo:

[CÓMO CONVERTIR UNA APLICACIÓN DE ANDROID EN UNA APLICACIÓN DEL SISTEMA](https://www.movilzona.es/tutoriales/android/root/como-convertir-una-aplicacion-de-android-en-una-aplicacion-del-sistema/)

[Convertir cualquier App a Aplicación de sistema en Android Root](http://movilandroide.blogspot.mx/2017/05/convertir-cualquier-app-aplicacion-de.html)