# Actualizar aplicacion en android 10 con apk desde codigo

Tags: android, apk

os comparto el trozo de codigo que me esta fallando.

Intento abrir una apk desde la propia aplicacion. Es una parte de codigo que siempre habia funcionado,pero esta fallando con las ultimas versiones de android(creo que desde la 7).

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/aplicacion.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        getGeneralController().getCurrentActivityOnTop().startActivity(intent);
```

Al ejecutarse salta este error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/download/aplicacion.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive }
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2081)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1737)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5429)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5379)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5781)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5734)
    at merca.android.mvc.view.activity.MenuActivity$DownloadFileFromURL.onPostExecute(MenuActivity.java:757)
    at merca.android.mvc.view.activity.MenuActivity$DownloadFileFromURL.onPostExecute(MenuActivity.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:771)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:199)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:788)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8057)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

¿Alguna sugerencia para las nuevas versiones?

Comment: Estás seguro que aplicacion.apk se encuentra en tu teléfono ?

Comment: Hola Sergio, debes agregar el permiso android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES  , pero tu aplicación debe ser de sistema, es difícil ya que necesitas el certificado con el que se firmo el firmware, revisa mi respuesta,saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Agrega a tu manifest el siguente permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

Comment: ya tiene este permiso,y aun asi salta esa excepcion

Answer (score 0):

Se debe agregar el permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

pero no es únicamente esto, si revisas el nivel de protección del permiso
[android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES) este indica "signature".

> "signature"   **Es un permiso que el sistema otorga solo si la aplicación
> solicitante está firmada con el mismo certificado que la aplicación
> que declaró el permiso.** Si los certificados coinciden, el sistema
> otorga automáticamente el permiso sin notificar al usuario ni
> solicitarle aprobación explícita.

Por lo tanto, **para poder asignar este permiso tu aplicación debe ser configurada como aplicación de sistema**, si tu aplicación no es de sistema, aunque tengas configurados los permisos, estos no podrán ser asignados.

Las aplicaciones de sistema son en realidad aplicaciones firmadas con la misma clave de firma que firmó el [firmware](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmware).

Te sugiero revisar:

[Error al emparejar dispositivo bluetooth](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/123922/error-al-emparejar-dispositivo-bluetooth/123978#123978)

Comment: Hola Jorge, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. El apk que intento abrir no es mas que una actualizacion de la actual apk...en versiones antiguas sigue funcionando bien. ¿De verdad para versiones actuales no hay un sistema mas "sencillo" para actualizar una app?

Comment: @SergioCv revisa acerca de actualizaciones integradas: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates#update_readiness